# Microscope Recommendations

Tags: microscopy, research-tools, biomedical-technology

I am a Engineering University student, in my last year of completion of my degree. I had interests in biochemistry and biology since I was a kid, and been learning about that side by side in my spare time.

I want to get into biomedical research and buy a suitable microscope for that purpose.

After following various guides and info I could find, I have decided to go for a well manufactured compound microscope of high quality. But these fishy companies majorly Chinese are troubling me, with top companies like Leica, Nikon, Zeiss etc having quite same reviews.

I haven't yet decided the Manufacturer I want to buy from. I am willing to go for around **$1000** for a well reputed manufacturer. There are numerous choices even within the top companies.

***What are some best suggestions and recommendations for Compound Microscope according to my needs?***

---

**all suggestions are welcomed.**

***edit 1***: Many Indian manufacturers called me, but I want some reliable global manufacturer, well known by its quality. I also need some expandable scope for future upgradations. Am I going the right way or should I buy from Indian manufacturers? and which manufacturer if well known one?

***edit 2***: The price I am going into is $1000.

Comment: What do you actually want to accomplish? A compound microscope isn't going to get you very far in biomedical research.

Comment: I am currently going for entry level one. Probably I will invest more later but for now, I want to get the basics clear.

Comment: Buy a microscope if you want to pursue a fascination with observing microscopic things as a hobby. But it will be of no use in biochemistry or molecular biology, where your hard skills are most likely to be applicable. The biochemistry labs in my university do not sport a single microscope, and I personally have only ever used one to check cell growth or virus infection (when I have to ask someone else how to use it).

Comment: Then I guess, currently I wish to do the basic things(not complex though). Thanks for clearing that out. But where should I start for getting one.

Comment: @David: And for a hobby-level microscope, $1500 is way overkill.  (I think I paid under $300 for mine, a few years ago.)  I think you would be better served by spending the extra money on things like a USB camera, polarizing filters, stains, &c.  Plus if you get a job in microbiology or some other field that requires microscope use, your employer will buy your equipment.

Comment: I used microscopes my whole adult life: provided by school or employers . I would look for a different job if  microscopes were not provided. Also , considerable support infrastructure is required for microscope  work.

Comment: @David Thanks for suggesting that. Maybe I should see the big picture instead of directly going for a high end one.

Comment: Can you suggest which manufacturer would be the best for that price range and quality?